# SSH Using YubiKey 5 and ED25519 Algorithm

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, sshd, yubikey

I am starting to use a YubiKey 5 to ssh into remote boxes instead of using a software key. I am generating the keys using this command:

`ssh-keygen -t ed25519-sk`

This works when I ssh into Ubuntu, but it does not work when I ssh into my Mac (macOS 11.4). I keep getting "Permission denied (publickey)" error. The ed25519 public key is in the "authorized_keys" file. I AM able to use keys that I generated using the RSA algorithm to ssh into the Mac. Below is my sshd_config file on my Mac.

Any thoughts on what may be causing my error?

```
#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.103 2018/04/09 20:41:22 tj Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication no
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM no

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#X11Forwarding no
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# pass locale information
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
```

Comment: What are the permissions on the public and privacy keys?

Comment: Public key permissions: -rw-r--r--
Private key permissions: -rw-------

Comment: That isn’t the full details. Your getting a permission error on the key which means owner of the file isn’t correct.  I would verify the recommendation on permissions on public keys for OpenSSH and verify that the owner is correct.  Looking at the verbose logs for the server might also help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, macOS 11.4 includes OpenSSH 8.1, which does not yet understand the new `-sk` key types. This feature was only added in OpenSSH 8.2.

("Security key" keypairs are a distinct type from "normal" Ed25519 keypairs, because U2F/FIDO keys cannot be used to sign arbitrary data – they only sign things that look like FIDO challenge messages – so the SSH client **and** the server must agree to format the SSH challenge in a different way than what's used for regular keypairs.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip - here is my version of OpenSSH and OpenSSL:

OpenSSH_8.6p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021

Comment: I checked again, and the host machine was defaulting to the system OpenSSH, which is 8.1. Thanks for the help!